# selecting and highlighting a day on a calendar with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, calendar

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="heading">
        <a class="previous-month" href="javascript:;"></a>
        <h1 class="hmc">February&nbsp;2012</h1>
        <a class="next-month" href="javascript:;"></a>
    </div>

    <ul class="week hmc">
        <li>Su</li>
        <li>Mo</li>
        <li>Tu</li>
        <li>We</li>
        <li>Th</li>
        <li>Fr</li>
        <li>Sa</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="january days hmc current">
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">9</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">10</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">11</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">12</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">13</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">14</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">15</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">16</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">17</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">18</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">19</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">20</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">21</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">22</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">23</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">24</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">25</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">26</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">27</a></li>
        <li><a class="alt current" href="javascript:;">28</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">29</a></li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here I generate a calendar. I want to highlight the current day I am clicking on. I have tried:

```
$('body').on('click', '.january > li > a', function() {             
    $(this).closest('.january').children('li').each(function() {
        var anchor = $(this).children('a');
        anchor.addClass('alt current');
    )}
)}
```

But it doesn't work. Also I want to select the value of the item I am clicking on, e.g. the day

Comment: can you please set this up on jsfiddle and update with url?

Comment: Please read up on how to format your HTML correctly.

Comment: There's a css rules-set(class) for `alt current`?

Comment: yes, there is a rule for alt current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traversal you are doing with `each()`, `closest()` and `children()` isn't necessary, try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.january > li > a', function() {
    $(".january > li > a").removeClass("alt current");            
    $(this).addClass('alt current');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', '.january > li > a', function() {

         $(this).closest('.january').children('li').each(function() {
             var anchor = $(this).children('a');
             anchor.addClass('alt current');
         });
});
```

The order of } and ) was not the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with bind event to links.

I use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".january li a").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('alt current');
    });
});
```

This script bind event click for addClass.